# What does SELECT do in dbase II PRG?

Tags: dbase

Trying to figure out what this code is doing:

SELECT 2 && DBACCT

GOTO VAL(ANUM)-AMIN

DBACCT is a database. ANUM was entered by the user. AMIN was set in the program prior. I tried looking up "SELECT" in the dbase documentation but it doesn't seem to match this code at all. Maybe this is some extension to dbase (foxpro?). Help!?

Comment: It chooses a workarea (a specific location for the table to use  for the commands that follow to use).

Comment: @KenWhite - I'm trying to convert this to PHP so I have to understand exactly what this is doing. Is it selecting 2 records in DBACCT starting at ANUM-AMIN to be used later?

Comment: No. As I said, `SELECT 2` chooses a workarea (basically a database handle). It has nothing to do with selecting data. It's **select**ing a workarea. IIRC, there were 10 workareas available, and you chose one to open a database in when you needed more than one open at a time. `SELECT 2` chooses the #2 workarea. In the case of the code you've posted, workarea 2 is where the DBACCT database was opened. The code moves to a specific record number (GOTO) based on a numeric value that is in the ANUM variable, which is being converted to a number, minus the value of the AMIN variable.

Comment: @KenWhite - Got it. Thank you! Appreciate your help.